# window.scroll() function glitch - scrolled header hide and show

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, shopify-template

I am trying to scale down the main desktop version of the logo in the site header when the site is scrolled. Once scrolling reaches a certain point, I want to completely hide the main desktop navigation bar and logo and instead show a different div that contains the smaller scrolled logo and navigation in a sticky header. This is working pretty well, with the issue being that in Chrome on Windows 10, when I scroll back up, I am sometimes not able to scroll all of the way to the top and have the full size logo and main nav some back into view. My code feels like it's certainly overkill, and I'm sure there has to be a way to simplify what I'm trying to do here. Anyone mind giving me some advice on the best practice and easiest way to achieve something like this?

Here is my current javascript/jQuery code:

```
(function($){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      
      if($(window).scrollTop() >= 86) {
        $('header.util').addClass('scrolled');
        $('#shopify-section-header > div:first-child').hide();
        $('#shopify-section-header').css('min-height','0');
        $('header.util .middle-wrapper').show().css("display", "inline-block");
      } else if($(window).scrollTop() >= 79) {
        $('header.util').removeClass('scrolled');
        $('#shopify-section-header header.site-header .logo-nav-contain .grid .grid__item.one-fifth').css('width','10%');
        $('header.site-header h1.site-logo.has-image a img').css('top','92px');
        $('#shopify-section-header').css('min-height','148px');
        $('#shopify-section-header > div:first-child').show();
        $('header.util .middle-wrapper').hide();
      } else if($(window).scrollTop() >= 72) {
        $('header.util').removeClass('scrolled');
        $('#shopify-section-header header.site-header .logo-nav-contain .grid .grid__item.one-fifth').css('width','11%');
        $('header.site-header h1.site-logo.has-image a img').css('top','84px');
        $('#shopify-section-header').css('min-height','148px');
        $('#shopify-section-header > div:first-child').show();
        $('header.util .middle-wrapper').hide();
      } else if($(window).scrollTop() >= 65) {
        $('header.util').removeClass('scrolled');
        $('#shopify-section-header header.site-header .logo-nav-contain .grid .grid__item.one-fifth').css('width','12%');
        $('header.site-header h1.site-logo.has-image a img').css('top','76px');
        $('#shopify-section-header').css('min-height','148px');
        $('#shopify-section-header > div:first-child').show();
        $('header.util .middle-wrapper').hide();
      } else if($(window).scrollTop() >= 58) {
        $('header.util').removeClass('scrolled');
        $('#shopify-section-header header.site-header .logo-nav-contain .grid .grid__item.one-fifth').css('width','13%');
        $('header.site-header h1.site-logo.has-image a img').css('top','69px');
        $('#shopify-section-header').css('min-height','148px');
        $('#shopify-section-header > div:first-child').show();
        $('header.util .middle-wrapper').hide();
      } else if($(window).scrollTop() >= 51) {
        $('header.util').removeClass('scrolled');
        $('#shopify-section-header header.site-header .logo-nav-contain .grid .grid__item.one-fifth').css('width','14%');
        $('header.site-header h1.site-logo.has-image a img').css('top','61px');
        $('#shopify-section-header').css('min-height','148px');
        $('#shopify-section-header > div:first-child').show();
        $('header.util .middle-wrapper').hide();
      } else if($(window).scrollTop() >= 44) {
        $('header.util').removeClass('scrolled');
        $('#shopify-section-header header.site-header .logo-nav-contain .grid .grid__item.one-fifth').css('width','15%');
        $('header.site-header h1.site-logo.has-image a img').css('top','54px');
        $('#shopify-section-header').css('min-height','148px');
        $('#shopify-section-header > div:first-child').show();
        $('header.util .middle-wrapper').hide();
      } else if($(window).scrollTop() >= 37) {
        $('header.util').removeClass('scrolled');
        $('#shopify-section-header header.site-header .logo-nav-contain .grid .grid__item.one-fifth').css('width','16%');
        $('header.site-header h1.site-logo.has-image a img').css('top','46px');
        $('#shopify-section-header').css('min-height','148px');
        $('#shopify-section-header > div:first-child').show();
        $('header.util .middle-wrapper').hide();
      } else if($(window).scrollTop() >= 30) {
        $('header.util').removeClass('scrolled');
        $('#shopify-section-header header.site-header .logo-nav-contain .grid .grid__item.one-fifth').css('width','17%');
        $('header.site-header h1.site-logo.has-image a img').css('top','38px');
        $('#shopify-section-header').css('min-height','148px');
        $('#shopify-section-header > div:first-child').show();
        $('header.util .middle-wrapper').hide();
      } else if($(window).scrollTop() >= 23) {
        $('header.util').removeClass('scrolled');
        $('#shopify-section-header header.site-header .logo-nav-contain .grid .grid__item.one-fifth').css('width','18%');
        $('header.site-header h1.site-logo.has-image a img').css('top','31px');
        $('#shopify-section-header').css('min-height','148px');
        $('#shopify-section-header > div:first-child').show();
        $('header.util .middle-wrapper').hide();
      } else if($(window).scrollTop() >= 14) {
        $('header.util').removeClass('scrolled');
        $('#shopify-section-header header.site-header .logo-nav-contain .grid .grid__item.one-fifth').css('width','19%');
        $('header.site-header h1.site-logo.has-image a img').css('top','23px');
        $('#shopify-section-header').css('min-height','148px');
        $('#shopify-section-header > div:first-child').show();
        $('header.util .middle-wrapper').hide();
      } else if($(window).scrollTop() <= 13){
        $('header.util').removeClass('scrolled');
        $('#shopify-section-header header.site-header .logo-nav-contain .grid .grid__item.one-fifth').css('width','20%');
        $('header.site-header h1.site-logo.has-image a img').css('top','14px');
        $('#shopify-section-header').css('min-height','148px');
        $('#shopify-section-header > div:first-child').show();
        $('header.util .middle-wrapper').hide();
      }
      
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: this is probably easily achieved with responsive CSS styling. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: @RickyG Can Media Queries be used for vertical scrolling breakpoints? I'm very familiar with using them for viewport width breakpoints, but haven't ever used them for vertical scrolling. The article you mention doesn't say anything about anything other than viewport width breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I have found a different approach based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27944562/14050245) from [@raad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1407999/raad).

Here is my updated and simplified code:

```
logoSize = function() {
  // Get the real width of the logo image
  var theLogo = $("#mainLogo");
  var newImage = new Image();
  newImage.src = theLogo.attr("src");
  var imgWidth = newImage.width;
  var imgHeight = newImage.height;

  // distance over which zoom effect takes place
  var maxScrollDistance = 92;

  // set to window height if larger
  maxScrollDistance = Math.min(maxScrollDistance, $(window).height());

  // width at maximum zoom out (i.e. when window has scrolled maxScrollDistance)
  var widthAtMax = 365;

  // calculate diff and how many pixels to zoom per pixel scrolled
  var widthDiff = imgWidth - widthAtMax;
  var pixelsPerScroll = (widthDiff / maxScrollDistance);

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    
    // the currently scrolled-to position - max-out at maxScrollDistance
    var scrollTopPos = Math.min($(document).scrollTop(), maxScrollDistance);
    
    // how many pixels to adjust by
    var scrollChangePx = Math.floor(scrollTopPos * pixelsPerScroll);
    
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var mainTop = $('.main-content').offset().top;
    var headerTop = $('#shopify-section-header').offset().top;
    var distanceMain = mainTop - windowTop;
    var distanceHeader = headerTop - windowTop;
    var stickyHeight = $('#shopify-section-promos').outerHeight() + $('header.util').outerHeight();
    var imgOffset = stickyHeight + 14;
    var positionTop = imgOffset - distanceHeader;
    
    // calculate the new width
    var zoomedWidth = imgWidth + scrollChangePx;
    
    var halfWidth = zoomedWidth / 2;
    halfWidth = -halfWidth;

    // set the width
    $('.logo').css('width', zoomedWidth);
    $('#mainLogo').css({
      'top': positionTop,
      'left': '50%',
      'margin-left': halfWidth
    });
    
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 86) {
      $('header.util').addClass('scrolled');
      $('#shopify-section-header > div:first-child').hide();
      $('#shopify-section-header').css('min-height','89px');
      $('header.util .middle-wrapper').show().css("display", "inline-block");
    } else {
      $('header.util').removeClass('scrolled');
      $('#shopify-section-header').css('min-height','148px');
      $('#shopify-section-header > div:first-child').show();
      $('header.util .middle-wrapper').hide();
    }
    
  });
}

logoSize();
```

This is working perfectly now!